# CSS Background-image layer add by CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a DOM element:

```
<div style="background-image: url(layer1.png)">...</div>
```

I want to add next layer using CSS:

```
div {
  background-image: url('layer2.png'),radial-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 0%, rgba(236, 245, 245, 0.19) 75%, rgba(236, 245, 245, 0) 100%);
}
```

As a result i need to have DIV with all 3 layers as a background image.
Is it possible by pure HTML5 CSS3?

Comment: Just add the next layer to a child and change opacity.

Comment: You want to add a new html element into your DOM using Css?

Comment: No i just want to have background image attribute of div contains all three layers. But layer1.png is a DB result, layer 2 and 3 should be editable by CSS. I simply dont want to overwrite CSS values by DOM attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. What will happen:

Your `div {}` rule has lower priority than inline css, so your inline css `background-image` will overwrite previous rule, not be appended to it.

Solution:

Use child element or `:before`/`:after` to apply `layer1.png`

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: radial-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 0%, rgba(236, 245, 245, 0.19) 75%, rgba(236, 245, 245, 0) 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div style="background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.85) 10%, rgba(0, 245, 0, 0.19) 75%, rgba(0, 245, 0, 0) 90%);"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but main reason of my question is for using background-blend-mode value, and for this i need all layers in one DOM. Is possible to use CSS variables? i simple don't know correct approach and using a javascript to edit DOM values seems like too heavy gear on this.

Comment: @Martin Then write all your backgrounds in inline-css

Answer (score 2):

Inline styling totally replaces the properties defined by CSS for that element.

What you can do is create a parent element and child elements as layers, then layer it with the help of `z-index` and then use `opacity` to give it some transparency.

HTML

```
<div class="layers">
  <div class="layer1" style="opacity: 0.2; background-image: url(foo.png);"> </div>
  <div class="layer2" style="opacity: 0.4;"></div>
  <div class="layer3" style="opacity: 0.2;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.layers{
  position:relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.layer1, .layer2, .layer3{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.layer1{ background-color: red; z-index: 0;}
.layer2{ background-color: orange; z-index: -1;}
.layer3{ background-color: pink; z-index: -2; }
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40ogt3sr/)